# Generating a File from a base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm using a webservice to get a base64 string and I need to show that document to the user as a PDF.

```
var charactersArray = atob(base64String);
var byteNumbers = new ArrayBuffer(charactersArray.length);

for (var i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = charactersArray.charCodeAt(i);
}

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

var file = new File([byteArray], "file.pdf", {
    type: "application/pdf",
});
```

I'm then using this "file" to create a url with

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

I'm opening this url in a button with the ng-click directive, but I'm getting loading the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the character codes to the `byteArray` rather than the `ArrayBuffer`

```
var charactersArray = atob(base64String);
var len = charactersArray.length;
var byteNumbers = new ArrayBuffer(len);

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = charactersArray.charCodeAt(i);
}

var file = new File([byteArray], "file.pdf", {
    type: "application/pdf",
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently work on a project like this and had the same issue. I used the [base64-arraybuffer NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer)  to convert a base64 string to a byte array.

It's a JS library so it needs to be imported like this after it's installed:

```
import * as buffer from 'base64-arraybuffer';
```

The object URL is created like this:

```
var byteArray = buffer.decode(base64String);
var file = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

I hope this helps!